# Any servers providing Muslim prayer time in JSON/XML?

Tags: iphone, ios, json

I need to get muslim prayer (Umm Al-qura  Makkah time) time to my iOS app. Are there any servers providing these information in either JSON or XML ?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61891905/12478830

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Like this? http://xhanch.com/xhanch-api-islamic-get-prayer-time/

According to this site, the following URL will return the desired data in JSON:

```
http://api.xhanch.com/islamic-get-prayer-time.php?lng=55&lat=25&yy=2012&mm=12&gmt=4&m=json
```

**Update**

Some additional resources, according to a few commenters (preserving here so they don't get lost)

- http://aladhan.com/rest-api
- https://prayertimes.date/api
- @obaid says "You can browse https://praytimes.org you will get a lot of resource on Namaz timings."

Comment: http://xhanch.com/api/islamic-get-prayer-time.php?lng=55&lat=25&yy=2012&mm=12&gmt=4&m=json

Comment: Just in case someone tries this, the domain has been updated to http://api.xhanch.com/islamic-get-prayer-time.php?lng=55&lat=25&yy=2012&mm=12&gmt=4&m=json

Comment: The time is not accurate as per Ummul Qura Mecca

Comment: @obaid Hmm ok. Can you elaborate in what way their JSON is not accurate? What is the difference between the Meccan Ummul Qura (is this the same as Umm al-Qura?), and the times returned by this API? This question seems to get a decent amount of hits, so if its not accurate, I wouldn't mind improving the answer to correct or explain any errors.

Comment: Yes, its not accurate I have the Library for php server and mobile platforms in how to calculate the timings standalone based on the moon angle and sun rising time along with the latitude and longitude. I'm not infront of the MAC pc. I'll post it soon

Comment: @obaid  how u got correct timings for namaz this site is not responinding me correct time

Comment: @Swayam how u got correct timings for namaz this site is not responinding me correct time

Comment: You can browse http://praytimes.org/ you will get a lot of resource on Namaz timings. Sorry I was late to put the answer.

Comment: Try http://aladhan.com/rest-api.

Comment: Can use this one too: https://prayertimes.date/api

Comment: Sadly, nothing works now.