# How is the Muslim Prayer time is calculated in an android application?

Tags: java, android, xml, json, time

I am doing my uni project to develop an android application. I have decided to develop an application that tells the user the daily times to pray for Muslims. But as I am new to android(and also programming in general) I don't know how to implement this. I have done some research myself and found that some web services provide JSON or XML files to fetch the data or there supposed to be Java Tools/Libs to use. Is there anyone who has developed or has experience in these topics.

please give some advices.

thank you

Comment: this might help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13833136/any-servers-providing-muslim-prayer-time-in-json-xml

Comment: @Dilshat you have good thought u need to get JSON or XML data and then parse it and show it.you will have to show accoring to the content u have

Comment: @khubaib I've seen that but the web side is not available and the json doe not give any information?

Comment: @Dipu is there source where I can find the JSON or XML files?

Comment: Don't idea will have to search but as u have mentain u have JSON or XML data

Comment: check this. this link has what you want
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560313/getting-info-from-api-using-json

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The **[Xhanch API](http://xhanch.com/xhanch-api-islamic-get-prayer-time/)** returns the data to you in JSON/XML format.

If you want XML,

```
http://api.xhanch.com/islamic-get-prayer-time.php?lng=30&lat=30&yy=2013&mm=9&gmt=4
```

If you want JSON,

```
http://api.xhanch.com/islamic-get-prayer-time.php?lng=30&lat=30&yy=2013&mm=9&gmt=4&m=json
```

Check the **[documentation](http://xhanch.com/xhanch-api-islamic-get-prayer-time/)** for the significance of each of the request parameters.

You can make a call to the API using **[KSOAP 2 library](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/)**.

This is how the JSON response looks like

`{"1":{"fajr":"05:16","sunrise":"06:36","zuhr":"13:00","asr":"16:34","maghrib":"19:23","isha":"20:40"},"2":{"fajr":"05:16","sunrise":"06:37","zuhr":"13:00","asr":"16:34","maghrib":"19:22","isha":"20:39"},"3":{"fajr":"05:17","sunrise":"06:38","zuhr":"13:00","asr":"16:33","maghrib":"19:21","isha":"20:38"},....
}`

Once you get the data in JSON format, all you need to do is **[parse the information](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)** and display it in your application.

Comment: is there any separate web service for different fiqa ?

Comment: Sorry, but that is something I am not aware of. You will have to check the website for more details.

Comment: @ Erum, you can check for calculation method(which fiqh you want to follow). Here is one link I just found that also have the option on method: http://muslimsalat.com/api/ or Aladhan API