# praying time in android (اوقات شرعی)

Tags: android

I tried this link in stack :

[How is the Muslim Prayer time is calculated in an android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930833/how-is-the-muslim-prayer-time-is-calculated-in-an-android-application)

and [this](http://xhanch.com/xhanch-api-islamic-get-prayer-time/) tutorial and parsed the response Json but it doesn't give correct times. I think I have problem in filling gmt part in request url. I have latitude and longitude of the location.

link example : http://api.xhanch.com/islamic-get-prayer-time.php?lng=50.0000&lat=36.2667&yy=2015&mm=9&gmt=?????????&m=json

What do I have to write in front of gmt in request url?

Thank you

**UPDATE :**

[this link](http://www.aladhan.com/rest-api) was my solution and the best API for muslim prayer times.

**this is my code :**

```
public void PrayerSendReq() {

    long unixTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;

    String urlStr = "http://api.aladhan.com/timings/" + unixTime + "?latitude=36.2687700&longitude=50.0041000&timezonestring=Asia/Tehran&method=7";


    Log.d("Prayer url : ", urlStr);
    // Volley request queue
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    JsonObjectRequest JOReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlStr, (String) null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    JSONObject JO = response;
                    Log.d("prayer resJson", response.toString());


                    JSONObject resultJO = new JSONObject();

                    try {
                        JSONObject items = JO.getJSONObject("data");
                        resultJO = items.getJSONObject("timings");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    Log.d("Last JO : ", resultJO.toString());

                    if (resultJO != null) {


                        try {
                            fajr = resultJO.getString("Fajr");
                            editor.putString("fajr", fajr);

                            sunrise = resultJO.getString("Sunrise");
                            editor.putString("sunrise", sunrise);

                            zuhr = resultJO.getString("Dhuhr");
                            editor.putString("zuhr", zuhr);

                            azanMaghrib = resultJO.getString("Maghrib");
                            editor.putString("azanMaghrib", azanMaghrib);

                            sunset = resultJO.getString("Sunset");
                            editor.putString("sunset", sunset);

                            editor.putString("exists", "sth");

                            editor.apply();


                            azanMaghribTv.setText(String.valueOf(prefs.getString("azanMaghrib", azanMaghrib)));

                            azanSobTv.setText(String.valueOf(prefs.getString("fajr", fajr)));

                            sunriseTv.setText(String.valueOf(prefs.getString("sunrise", sunrise)));

                            azanZohrTv.setText(String.valueOf(prefs.getString("zuhr", zuhr)));

                            sunsetTv.setText(String.valueOf(prefs.getString("sunset", sunset)));


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }


                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    // add it to the RequestQueue
    queue.add(JOReq);

}
```

**and inside activity oncreate:**

```
    azanSobTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pray_ac_sob);
    sunriseTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pray_ac_toloo);
    azanZohrTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pray_ac_zohr);
    azanMaghribTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pray_ac_maghrib);
    sunsetTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pray_ac_sunset);



    azanSobTv.setTypeface(Fonts.TrafficB);
    sunriseTv.setTypeface(Fonts.TrafficB);
    azanZohrTv.setTypeface(Fonts.TrafficB);
    azanMaghribTv.setTypeface(Fonts.TrafficB);
    sunsetTv.setTypeface(Fonts.TrafficB);

    PrayerSendReq();

    if (prefs.getString("exists", null) != null) {

        azanMaghribTv.setText(String.valueOf(prefs.getString("azanMaghrib", azanMaghrib)));

        azanSobTv.setText(String.valueOf(prefs.getString("fajr", fajr)));

        sunriseTv.setText(String.valueOf(prefs.getString("sunrise", sunrise)));

        azanZohrTv.setText(String.valueOf(prefs.getString("zuhr", zuhr)));

        sunsetTv.setText(String.valueOf(prefs.getString("sunset", sunset)));
    }
```

Comment: FYI - if you are still using this, I suggest you subscribe to the mailing list @ http://aladhan.com/contact. I've added information about additonal endpoints to the website too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter the timezone of the location. 
Refer http://unattended.sourceforge.net/timezones.php for list of timezones.

For example, if you want Pacific Time, enter 4.